# Update a boolean field in db using link_to

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have boolean field in the database, how can I update it in rails using link_to. I want to have two link_to commands. One for true another for false.

how do i do it? I can use ajax, but i wanna learn to pass the data first.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`link_to` can only link to a target controller action. You need to define a route that will route the call to a method that toggles the boolean value.

For example, in your controller:

```
class ThingsController
  def toggle_foo
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
    @thing.foo = !@thing.foo
    @thing.save
  end
end
```

Then you would route this:

```
resources :things,
  :member => { :toggle_too => :put }
```

Then you can link to it:

```
link_to('Toggle', toggle_foo_thing_path(@thing), :method => :put)
```

It's important to **not** use a `GET` method on these calls because some browsers will pre-load all the simple links on your page, which will have the effect of automatically toggling all those things you link to on the page.

Comment: I have a field in db which says `products` which is boolean. in the code above how do I toggle? Plus i am looking to have two buttons Agree and disagree. If agree is hit then its true, else otherwise.

Comment: Well, that's a case of setting the appropriate label, maybe having an `if` to show one of two possible states. What you're asking for is exceedingly specific. Hopefully you can adapt that example as required.